# Paste image URL to html text box instead of 'browsing for file'

Tags: image, upload, textbox, submit

How can I convert the following into an editable text box, with a submit button to carry out the code below?

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" />
```

The use case is that an image URL is in the memory, and just needs to be pasted for submission, instead of choosing a local file.  (since the OS grabs the remote file, makes a local copy of it then passes this on)

I'm essentially tweaking this element from a nice jcrop tutorial:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/

Many thanks!

Comment: Format code as code, otherwise your html will be invisible.

Comment: Use `type="text"` rather than `type="file"`.

Comment: thanks, but changing the type does not give a submit button near the textbox. Also, when pressing enter after pasting in a valid image URL (for example, a local image) it seems the file is no longer obtained.  (Yet pasting a file URL into the original Browse dialogue would obtain it - remote or local file)  Many thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing passing on a manually specified file name to upload, has been prevented due to security reasons.